# cypress ParseError on css content

Tags: cypress

I am new to Cypress for javascrpt testing.  I'm testing a basic react app with css.  Whether I import css directly or use css modules, the test always fails with:

```
ul {
   ^
ParseError: Unexpected token
```

That ParseError is shown in the cypress test runner.  It also has this text in the test runner sidebar:

> This occurred while Cypress was compiling and bundling your test code.
>   This is usually caused by:
>
> A missing file or dependency A syntax error in the file or one of its
>   dependencies Fix the error in your code and re-run your tests.

Even with an out of the box create-react-app app, the App.test.js will fail due to css ParseError on App.css.

Does anything need to be done in Cypress config to address this?

Here is the simple css file:

```
ul {
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
  }

  li {
    float: left;
  }
```

The test file:

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import App from '../../src/App.js';

describe('Default React App.js test', () => {
    it('renders without crashing', () => {
        const div = document.createElement('div');
        ReactDOM.render(<App />, div);
        ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);
    });
})

describe('basic ui test', () => {
    it('finds text on page', () => {
        cy.visit('http://localhost:3000');
        cy.contains('home');
    })
})
```

Comment: How are you running things? Cypress does not compile the app, it runs automation against a running web site.

Comment: @eric99 Added the test file showing the two tests.  If I remove the 'basic ui test', I'll get the same ParseError message for App.css.  I have cypress running, and the react app running in my local (localhost:3000)

Comment: The 2nd test is the way Cypress is (normally) run. You may get somewhere with the first test if you construct an `index.html` file and invoke it as per [visit - Web Server](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/visit.html#Web-Server).

Comment: In their examples, they have an example react unit test, which is a standard React-ish unit/integration test.  Only, their example component does not use css.  So, theoretically, a simple render should work.

https://github.com/cypress-io/cypress-example-recipes/blob/master/examples/unit-testing__react-enzyme/cypress/integration/unit-test-react-enzyme-spec.js

Comment: Just saw this on their plugins page: 

"Loading and mounting components from various frameworks is highly experimental and might change in the future."

I think I'll stick with Enzyme, Jest, etc for typical react testing, and use cypress only for E2E/browser testing.

Comment: Indeed, unit testing with Cypress is mentioned often, but dependent on framework compilation. In my experience, it works ok with Vue but not at all with Angular (2+).

Answer (score 0):

The `window/document` of the spec is not the same as your app, so this does not work out of the box.

For unit testing react, see this repo: https://github.com/bahmutov/cypress-react-unit-test