# Cypress issue with SCSS file when importing component

Tags: reactjs, cypress

I'm writing unit tests for a React application using Cypress.  I wish to use the 'cypress-react-unit-test' to test individual components.

I am only importing React, cypress-react-unit-test (in support/index.js) and the component itself.

I have a simple component (test.js)

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import "./test.css"

class Test extends Component{
    render(){
        return(
            <h1>Testing {this.props.name}</h1>
        )
    }
}

export default Test;
```

along with a test.scss containing

```
h1 { 
    color: blue
}
```

When I start the test runner I get an error preparing test file referring to the test.css file
[image]

Can someone explain what is going on here?

Same issue as this [cypress ParseError on css content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54496721/cypress-parseerror-on-css-content), but I am already using the cypress-react-unit-test package.  As said there, if I comment out the import css file in the component file, the component renders without any styling.  But what if I want to assert a heading's colour for example?

My starting testcode

```
import React from 'react'
import Test from '../../../../src/components/test.js'

describe('testing React', ()=>{

    it('should react', ()=>{
        cy.mount(<Test name="Nrd" />)
        cy.contains('Testing')
    })
})
```

Comment: Error is clear that you are missing some dependency or may be syntax issue. Have you check both these things?

Comment: The application itself runs as it should, and all the dependencies/dev-dependencies that I believe are required for this particular test are present in the package.json file.
I have added my testcode for more context.